# javascript to create a random table generator and assign color to cells

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function createTable()
    {
        var num_rows = document.getElementById('rows').value;
        var num_cols = document.getElementById('rows').value;
        var theader = '<table border="">\n';
        var tbody = '';
        var randomNumber = function (min, max)
        {
            return Math.floor (Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
        }

        for( var i=0; i<num_rows;i++)
        {
            tbody += '<tr>';
            for( var j=0; j<num_rows;j++)
            {
                tbody += '<td>';
                tbody += ' ' + randomNumber(1,100)  ;
                tbody += '</td>'

            }
            tbody += '</tr>\n';
        }
        var tfooter = '</table>';
        document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML = theader + tbody + tfooter;
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="tablegen">
    <label>Rows: <input type="text" name="rows" id="rows"/></label><br />

    <input name="generate" type="button" value="Create Table!" onclick='createTable();'/>
</form>

<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

This is the code I have. It creates the table from the user input and randomly generates a number but now I'm trying to figure out how to creating the array you will loop through it and if the number is a multiple of 3, display the cell with a
red background color; if not a multiple of 3 but a multiple of 2, display the cell with a blue background I can't figure it out.

Comment: Could you please format your code properly ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the inner loop:

```js
for( var i=0; i<num_rows;i++)
{
    tbody += '<tr>';
    for( var j=0; j<num_rows;j++)
    {
        var ranNum = randomNumber(1,100);
        var color;
        if(ranNum % 3 == 0) {
            color = 'red';
        } else if(ranNum % 2 == 0) {
            color = 'blue';
        } else {
            color = 'white';
        }
        tbody += '<td style="background-color:' + color + '">';
        tbody += ' ' + ranNum;
        tbody += '</td>'

    }
    tbody += '</tr>\n';
}
```

Comment: ok 2 questions after that is there a site that helps teach you this im using code academy now but do you know of any other ones also if i wanted to find the average of the random numbers how would i go about doing that

Comment: To find the average you simply need to add all of the numbers together and then divide by the count of numbers. Just create a variable to hold the sum, add the current number to it during each inner loop, then divide by the count of numbers when done. Code academy is excellent.

Comment: so var sum = ranNum + num_rows     as the variable but how do i add in the current number

Comment: No, "sum += ranNum". You want to add the current number to sum of all previous numbers.

Comment: var sum = " " that way its open? and then on every if statement put what you wrote

Comment: Create a 'sum' variable before your loops and set it equal to 0. Inside of your inner loop add the ranNum to it. That will give you the sum of all of the randomly generated numbers. After the loops just divide it by the number of cells, or "sum/(num_rows*num_rows)"

Comment: so i added the "sum += ranNum in all the if and else if statements but for the last one is that where i divide

Comment: i did that and the numbers are not averaging out correctly